# JAXB self closing tag marshaling

Tags: java, jaxb

How do marshal a self-closing tag with JAXB (Java).

i.e. the class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement public String name;
    @XmlElement public int age;
    @XmlAttribute public int id;

}
```

Would marshal to:

```
<customer id="3">
    <name>TEST</name>
    <age>100</age>
</customer>
```

If I wanted something like an element `<something data='whatever'/>` inside Customer, is there an annotation for this?

EDIT:

To clarify, what I would like is:

```
<customer id="3">
    <name>TEST</name>
    <age>100</age>
    <something data='whatever'/>
</customer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a fixed (static) value

```
@XmlAttribute(name="data")
private final static String DATA = "whatever";
```

Comment: That's didn't seem to work, but also, I would like to be able to set the variable, so `static` wouldn't work for me. I made an edit. Thanks for the help though.